# Get distance to walk in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to do some experiment with an app. I want that, given my location and given a distance, I get a point in Google Map to which I could walk that distance.

That has some complications since getting a point X miles out from you is "easy" but it's unlikely you'll actually walk that amount of miles unless you can actually go in a straight line.

The approach I followed is using `google.maps.places.PlacesService` and the function `nearbySearch` given a `radius`. Then I process the distance to each returned point and luckily I get one point I could walk that distance far.

However, I've been trying some edge cases, like picking a road near a desert and then it won't work cause "places" are points of interest and that may be only just a plain road with nothing else than boring bushes for a long, long way.

In my mind it just should follow that road for the given distance and then stop.

To be clear:

I want to know from my `starting` point, which would be my `ending` point if I were to walk 1 Km

Do you have any better approach to this kind of situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`google.maps.DirectionsService` class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsService) will calculate the route a traveller would take, given an `origin` and a `destination`. It accepts a [`google.maps.DirectionsRequest` object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRequest). The DirectionsRequest has an option called `TravelMode`, which will accept any of four constants (BICYCLING, DRIVING, TRANSIT, **WALKING**) from the [`google.maps.TravelMode` class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#TravelMode).

To find a point, say, **3 kilometers** from your location, I would:

1. Request walking directions from `DirectionsService`, using your current location and a point approximately **3 kilometers** away from you.
2. Iterate over the `overview_path`, continually adding the length of the current segment to your grand total.
3. Cut the last segment to length when you exceed **3 kilometers**, creating a length whose final length is very close to **3 kilometers**.

I made you [a Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z7RbzFx6AqG6xY1cpa2Y?p=preview) demonstrating how this could be done.

Comment: That's not good :) I want to know from my `starting` point, which would be my `ending` point if I were to walk 1 Km

Comment: Ooh, that's tricky! So if you give it 1km, it should find a route that starts where you are, walks 1km total, and returns you to your original location?

Comment: Without the part of returning you to the original location. I just want to know a point which is 1km away (walking) of my current location.

Comment: How can you "Keep a running total of the distance until you reach approximately" ?

Comment: Sir, you're the best! That was enlightening for me! Massive thank you ;-) I'd awarded the bounty even if I didn't started!